# How to expand a variable stored in a text file

Tags: powershell

Given the following bit of json saved in a file.

```
{
    "Username":  "userbob",
    "Password":  "$password"
}
```

How can I read that file (to a variable), and expand the $password variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read it into a (single) string and call [`ExpandString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
$password = "s3cr3tz"

# Read into string variable:
$jsonTemplate = Get-Content -Raw

# Expand string
$json = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($jsonTemplate)
```

This will cause the parser to expand the string:

```
PS C:\> $json |ConvertFrom-Json

Username Password
-------- --------
userbob  s3cr3tz
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet, convert it using [ConvertFrom-Json](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217031) and finally [select](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) the password.

```
Get-Content "c:\yourjsonfile.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | select -expand Password
```